# How to push changes to production without affecting users working on it

Tags: node.js, express

My application in production is hosted on heroku.

Each time I push changes to it, the application restarts.

So, if a user is logged in - they are logged out.

If a user was working on something, then the user loses his data.
Say the user was filling up a form. Since the application has restarted, submitting the form has no effect. The user has to log in again and fill the form all over.

How do I push to production without affecting existing users data?

I read somewhere about a module that will allow pushes to production without affecting existing user data. That is, if the user is working on something, then a process is created which allows the user to work without interruptions.
When production is updated, the process is not.

Any idea how I can go about with this?

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here to provide anything other than general feedback.  Are you using a framework like Express?  It sounds like you need to make sure that the user sessions are persistent between application starts, rather than just in application memory.  You could also use cluster to start your application as a worker, then maintain session state in the master, when you update your worker application, just restart your workers.  But without knowing more about your application architecture, there's no way to know what the best option might be.

Comment: @Jason Yes, I am using Express.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Heroku, then you automatically get a deployment system which ensure no downtime for users. A new version of you app is deployed and hot-swapped with the old one.

If your users are being logged out it is probably because the session data is being wiped when the app is restarted.

To avoid this, use a persistent session store, like `redis-connect`.

```
var express = require("express")
  , redis = require("redis")
  , RedisStore = require("connect-redis")(express);

app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.session({
    store: new RedisStore({
      client: redis
    })
  });
});
```

The code above is an example, you'll find more at https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis.